# Vi multiple command in one line

Tags: vim, vi

I want to achieve the following things in vi :

- Remove first few columns
- Remove lines starting with specific words
- Remove everything after first word.

I have the following command with respect to above requirements

`:%s/new  page   //g` to remove first two columns.
`:g/abc/d` , `:g/xyz/d` , `:g/ddd/d` to remove lines starting with specific words.
`:%s/ .*//g` to remove everything after first word.

Overall I want to run the following commands :

`:%s/new  page   //g`
`:g/abc/d`
`:g/xyz/d`
`:g/ddd/d`
`:%s/ .*//g`

How can I execute all the above commands in one single command.

I have tried `|` but it did not worked.

`:g/abc/d|:g/xyz/d|:g/ddd/d`

I am getting the following error :

`E147: Cannot do :global recursive`

How can I achieve this. I want to execute all commands in one single command.

Thanks

Comment: You can't add other commands after a `:g`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put all those commands in a function:

```
function! AllMyCommands()
    %s/new  page   //g
    g/abc/d
    g/xyz/d
    g/ddd/d
    %s/ .*//g
endfunction
```

and call it either directly:

```
:call AllMyCommands()
```

or via a custom command:

```
command! Foo call AllMyCommands()
:Foo
```

or via a custom mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :<C-u>call AllMyCommands()<CR>
<key>
```

Comment: You can actually use :g/pattern/cmd1|cmd2|cmd3...

Comment: One can certainly do `:g/pattern/cmd1|cmd2|cmd3` but `cmd1`, `cmd2`, and `cmd3` are all executed within the context of `:g`, which may or may not be desired. For example, one may want to delete matching lines and then perform a substitution on the lines below: `:g/pattern/d|s/foo/bar/g`. Chaining works, here, because we actually want the second command to be executed for each match. But if one wants to delete matching lines and then write to disk, doing `:g/pattern/d|w` will write the file n times for n matches, which is probably not the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4):

> I have tried | but it did not worked.
>
> ```
> :g/abc/d|:g/xyz/d|:g/ddd/d
> ```

In general, commands can be executed sequentially, separated by `|`, but there are exceptions, as `:help :bar` tells:

> ```
> These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
> followed by another Vim command:
> [...]
> :global
> [...]
> ```

As a workaround, you can wrap them in `:execute`:

```
:exe 'g/abc/d'|exe 'g/xyz/d'|g/ddd/d
```

But putting them into a `:function`, as per @romainl's answer, is probably better.

Comment: Why is the |exe only appearing between the first and second commands, and not between the second and third commands?

Comment: @Nike The last command in the sequence does not require the `exe` as there's no other command following (that would be affected by the greedy argument parsing of `:g` et al.). You can put it there as well, but it's not necessary.